# Facebook login dialog is dismissed automatically when the button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm working on an iOS App which uses Firebase + Facebook Authentication to sign in and authenticate the user. The functionality works, it is only when the Continue with facebook button is clicked, it automatically dismisses the dialog box before the user can click continue or cancel.

I've uploaded a [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP8rP.jpg) as an example for better explanation, the first time I clicked it, it works but after trying it for the second or third time and even after closing the app and launching it again, the issue is still there.

Here's the code snippet from my `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookCore

var fbAccessToken: AccessToken?

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
        FirebaseApp.configure()

        // Facebook
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // Added from Firebase docs -- Google
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        // FB Auth
        let handled: Bool = SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url,  sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]!)

        if !handled{
        // Google Auth
            print("clicked google sign in")
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: [:])
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here's the code snippet from my `ViewController.Swift`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
import FacebookCore
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FacebookLogin

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var FbLogin: FBSDKLoginButton! // Facebook Login button

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set delegates
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()

        FbLogin.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignInWithFacebookTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func handleSignInWithFacebookTapped() {
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logIn(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .email], viewController: self ){ (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(grantedPermissions: _, declinedPermissions: _, token: _):
                print("Succesfully logged into facebook")
                self.signIntoFirebase()
            case .failed(let err):
                print(err)
            case .cancelled:
                print("cancelled")
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func signIntoFirebase(){
        guard let authenticationToken = AccessToken.current?.authenticationToken else {return}
        let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: authenticationToken)
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
                return
            }
            print("Sucessfully hit Firebase")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginPush", sender: self)
                print("Logged in successfully")
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the image of the Connections Inspector for the button:

[image]

Comment: If the user already accepted all the permissions you are asking for, then they will not be asked again the next time the log in … this is _supposed_ to work this way.

Comment: What I've been able to figure out is that when the `LoginManager` is loaded it directly goes to the `case .cancelled`, without the user clicking it